# What does dot mean in SQL query

Tags: sql

In the w3school tutorial for the SQL "JOIN command", the given example is:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

My question is what does the dots mean in `Orders.OrderID`, `Customers.CustomerName`, `Orders.OrderDate` and so on?

Answer (score 3):

In this particular example it separates table name with column name.
It helps when two or more tables have columns with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

in this case: **Orders.OrderID**
the **OrderID** is a column in **Orders** table.
lets asume, that **OrderID** is a column in **Customers** table,
you must define from which table you wish to get the OrderID column

Answer (score 1):

In this case:

*TableName.Column*

You might also see aliases

e.g.

```
SELECT a.column1, b.column2
FROM Table1 AS a
JOIN Table2 AS b
```

Comment: sorry I am absolute beginner ... please try to explain it to me as to the stupidest man ever... :(
What is "schema", "owner", "object name"

Comment: much better like this! Thank you